# Turn vector values into list of vectors R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a vector of n elements, character strings all of them. Random example might be with *names*:

`[1] Tim Tom Berta ... n`

which I want to turn into be separated into a list of vectors looking like that:

```
Names
$name:
[1] Tim
$name
[1] Tom
$name
[1] Berta
...
$name
[1] n
```

To give some context, why: The reason is given through the procedure of the rDNA package of R to exclude certain data. For example calculate a cluster analysis of actor-concept-network, but with only of subgroup of the concepts (highlighted).

```
congruence <- dna_network(conn,
           networkType = "onemode",
           statementType = "DNA Statement",
           variable1 = "organization",
           **variable2 = "concept",**
           qualifier = "agreement",
           qualifierAggregation = "congruence",
           duplicates = "document",
           **excludeValues = list("concept" =
                                  "There should be legislation to regulate emissions.")**)
```

Comment: You can use `as.list` i.e. `Name <- as.list(yourvector)`  It is not clear why you want the list elements to have same `name`.  `names(Name) <- rep("name", length(yourvector))`

Comment: Thank you, akrun. I have to pushed this problem which is essential but only at a later stage into the future (which is now). So. Thank you, but naming code does not work, because it only does name the first vector leaving the others NA (instead of being numbered as before). ... for which the solution is to leave "length()" out. so names(Listname) <- rep("name", 5) ... (of any other number)